# Error TypeError: inputCalle is null en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Realizando un Sistema con **PHP** y **JavaScript** me encuentro en la siguiente problemática:

Tengo un `select` con un evento `onChange` para que dependiendo de lo seleccionado me habilite o deshabilite unos campos, pero el problema que al cambiar el valor del `select` me arroja el siguiente error en consola:

> TypeError: inputCalle is null

Mi código del formulario:

```
<label>Domicilio si es distinto al del alumno(a):</label><br>
<select class="select" name="domicilio" onchange="habilitarDomicilio(this);">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="si">Si</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select><br>
<label>Calle:</label><br>
<input class="in-inp" type="text" name="calle" id="calle"  disabled></input><br>
<label>Número:</label><br>
<input class="in-inp" type="text" name="numero" id="numero" maxlength="5" disabled></input><br>
<label>Colonia:</label><br>
<input class="in-inp" type="text" name="colonia" id="colonia" maxlength="40" disabled></input><br>
<label>Código Postal:</label><br>
<input class="in-inp" type="number" name="cp" id="cp" min="5" max="5" disabled></input><br>
<label>Municipio:</label><br>
<input class="in-inp" type="text" name="municipio" id="municipio" maxlength="50" disabled></input><br>
<label>Estado:</label><br>
<input class="in-inp" type="text" name="estado" id="estado" maxlength="35" disabled></input><br>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
var inputCalle = document.getElementById("calle");
var inputNumero = document.getElementById('numero');
var inputColonia = document.getElementById('colonia');
var inputCP = document.getElementById('cp');
var inputMunicipio = document.getElementById('municipio');
var inputEstado = document.getElementById('estado');
function habilitarDomicilio(elemento) {
    d = elemento.value;
    if(d == "si"){
        inputCalle.disabled = false;
        inputCalle.required = true;

        inputNumero.disabled = false;
        inputNumero.required = true;

        inputColonia.disabled = false;
        inputColonia.required = true;

        inputCP.disabled = false;
        inputCP.required = true;

        inputMunicipio.disabled = false;
        inputMunicipio.required = true;

        inputEstado.disabled = false;
        inputEstado.required = true;
    }else{
        inputCalle.disabled = true;
        inputCalle.value = "";
        inputCalle.required = false;

        inputNumero.disabled = true;
        inputNumero.value = "";
        inputNumero.required = false;

        inputColonia.disabled = true;
        inputColonia.value = "";
        inputColonia.required = false;

        inputCP.disabled = true;
        inputCP.value = "";
        inputCP.required = false;

        inputMunicipio.disabled = true;
        inputMunicipio.value = "";
        inputMunicipio.required = false;

        inputEstado.disabled = true;
        inputEstado.value = "";
        inputEstado.required = false;
    }
}
```

Ya intente cambiando los *id´s* de los elementos pero me sigue arrojando el mismo error, al igual tengo otros métodos que hacen lo mismo y si funcionan. ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: ¿Tienes el javascript (la etiqueta `<script>`antes o después de este HTML? Creo que lo tienes antes (en el head, quiza?), pero deberías tenerlo al final del archivo HTML

Comment: De paso el tag `<input>` **no** tiene pareja `</input>`. Puedes dejarlo sin cerrar or si prefieres terminarlo con `/` en el mismo tag: `<input id="calle" />`

Comment: Ese era el problema, la ubicación del archivo.

Comment: @PabloLozano, lo podría tener también al principio, pero dentro de un listener de [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded).